# Adding global MySQL exception handler

Tags: mysql, vb.net

In my dll, I have a global error handler to catch the rest of the errors. The handler is added in the Load-event:

```
 AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MYExnHandler
```

And the sub looks like this:

```
Private Sub MYExnHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Dim EX As Exception
    EX = DirectCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)
    MsgBox(EX.ToString())
End Sub
```

This works very fine. Is there a way to use a global error handler for MySQL-expections in the same way? I want to catch especially the MySQLCommand in the exception.

Comment: Don't do it like that in the first place.  In VB applications, there's an `UnhandledApplication` event that already exists and you can just handle that.  Click the *View Application Events* button in the project properties to open the appropriate file and create your event handler there.  This will catch ALL exceptions that you don't catch explicitly, including any thrown by MySQL types.

Comment: Ah, got you, jmcilhinney! I was a little bit wrong in my text. In applications, I use the event you mentioned of course. But this is a dll, and I did not found something similar, this is because I took the code mentioned. And of course in my real sub, there is no MsgBox.